# NginX Cross-Loadbalance

Tags: nginx, load-balancing

Let's say you have 2 web servers. Both has NginX installed. You want to load balance the traffic between them. How do you do that in nginx.conf?

Server1:

```
http {
  upstream myproject {
    ip_hash;
    server 127.0.0.1:8000;
    server 10.0.0.2:8000;
  }

  server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.domain.com;
    location / {
      proxy_pass http://myproject;
    }
  }
}
```

Server2:

```
http {
  upstream myproject {
    ip_hash;
    server 127.0.0.1:8000;
    server 10.0.0.1:8000;
  }

  server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.domain.com;
    location / {
      proxy_pass http://myproject;
    }
  }
}
```

Should this work or is it a complete failure?

Comment: This doesn't look like it's going to be very effective at load balancing. Even if a server proxies to it's peer, it's still buffering and proxying that request. You need to split the requests among the servers before it gets to either of them. This requires a load balancer external to both of them. Sometimes this is done with DNS, by having multiple records for a given domain name.

Comment: So the best is then, to just have one of them load balancing and let it desice to keep the connection to itself or ffw it to the other server. Yeah, I think you are 100% right.

Comment: Not really, no. I'm saying that you need 3 separate servers to load balance between 2 servers. With multiple DNS records they DNS server acts as the 3rd server doing the load balancing. Of course your specifics and why you need to load balance matters a lot to saying how you can achieve that.